# Parent div with a background-image "collapses" when adding a child div

Tags: html, css

I am attempting to create a game where the first thing that the user sees is a start-menu modal on top of a game background.

Basic HTML:

```
<div class="game-board"> 
   <div class="menu"> </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
html, body{
    min-height:100%;
} 

.game-board{
    background-image: url(../images/sand.png);
    width: 1260px;
    height: 100%;
}

.menu{
  position: absolute;
  width: 400px;
  right: 0;
  top: 30%;
  left: 31%;
  background: whitesmoke;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
```

I expected the above code to show the background-image in the background, and then somewhere near the middle of the image, the "modal" is above the background. However, for some reason that I'd love to know, the parent `div .game-board` is collapsed with no height and thus no background image, but the modal appears fine. Why is this?

Answer (score 1):

Rule - For height in percentage to work in CSS, the parent element should have a height that can be calculated.

For example, when you say `.game-board` should have a `height` of 100% - then the question that arises is 100% of what? Because the parent element `body` in this case, does not have height specified explicitly. `Min-height` does not work because that does not fix the height of the element to a particular value on a particular view port. For example, if the viewport has height 100px then `min-height: 100%` could mean anything from 100px to infinity. Thus the `height` rule on `.game-board` doesn't work.

To fix this, change `min-height` to `height`

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
```

Also, the absolutely positioned menu, needs to have a height if there is no content as of yet inside it, else it would not appear.

Here is a working fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/8dhfac8w/

Answer (score 1):

`.game-board` needs a fixed height. `.menu` can do with a variable height so long as it's contained by a fixed height parent. This works ([Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/scue9ofe/1/)).

```
    html, body{
      min-height:100%;
    } 

    .game-board{
      background-image: url("http://trikkiworld.com/images/bg/bg_sand/25012011/sand006.jpeg");
      width: 200px;
      height: 200px;
    }

    .menu{
      position: relative;
      width: 50%;
      height: 50%;
      top: 25%;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
      display: block;
      background: whitesmoke;
      border-radius: 4px;
    }
```